# How do I improve performance using TPT in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've been building application using [TPT](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) (Table-Per-Type) in entity framework 6.

I have these classes

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    public string BillingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Vendor : Person
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class IndividualCustomer : Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}

public class CorporateCustomer : Customer
{
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string CorporateTaxNo { get; set; }
}

public class SalesInvoice
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

The query is very ugly and took a long time to generate when i query against the base class (which are Person and Customer), But quite ok when querying the derived class (IndividualCustomer & CorporateCustomer).

I have read that using TPT is very bad for performance and i'm considering to use [TPH](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) (Table-Per-Hierarchy) because of this. But when i use TPH, when adding SalesInvoice, i will have to validate if the user is sending the correct CustomerId. Because database will allow the user sending a vendorid as CustomerId. While using TPT, database will throw error. So TPH will add complexity when doing CRUD.

Are there any suggestion how to improve TPT query on my case?

**Note:**

I found that when querying the base class, if i specify which fields i want to retrieve, eg Select(x => new {x.Id, x.Name}), the query looks better and does not include left outer join the derived classes.

**My Queries:**

```
//Querying base class
var people = ctx.People.Select(x => new {x.Id, x.Name}).ToList();

//Querying derived class
var corporates = ctx.CorporateCustomers.ToList();
```

Comment: Can you add the query (the linq syntax, not the generated sql) to your question?

Comment: While I'm 90% certain that I know what you mean by `TPT` and `TPH`, I think it'd be a good idea to edit your question to clarify it a bit.

Comment: The design phenomena of TPT as well as TPH both refer to the relational database design that will fetch records from all the related tables depending heavily on the linq query. So, performance might be affected.